# How can I get MS Access to immediately read in all the data from a PG backend?

Tags: ms-access

MS Access
Microsoft 365 for enterprise

I have a MS Access frontend to a Postgres backend (table with 5000 lines).  It works fine except for the scroll bar. When I drag the scroll bar down to the bottom, it springs back up some distance, indicating there's more to read. I drag it back down and again, the same thing.  If I keep repeating this enough times, It'll eventually get to the 5000'th line at the bottom and that behavior stops.

I get that it may not have had time to read all the lines in, initially.  But it demonstrates this behavior even if I wait more than enough time to read all the lines in.  If I sort one of the columns, forcing it to read everything in, then the scroll bars work as expected (no springing back).

Q: How can I prevent this springing back of the scroll bar, presumably by getting it to read in all the records ?

Answer (score 2):

Access avoids reading in all lines when it can, to avoid needlessly loading and locking records.

If you want to avoid that, just navigate to the last record, by pressing the <kbd>>|</kbd> button at the bottom, next to the record count. That will force Access to load all records.

Comment: PERFECT !
Thanks Erik.